# I have a report which is getting this error

Tags: reporting-services

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> The execution failed for the shared data set 'TargetYear'. (rsDataSetExecutionError)
> Cannot create a connection to data source ' Data source for shared dataset'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

I am getting this error while opening an SSRS report.

Comment: it looks like the report cannot connect to a data source. Have you checked that the data source exists and that you can access it.

Comment: It could be a permission issue with the account your using to access the data source

Comment: The error says that the data source for the *Shared Data Set* TargetYear has some issue. This is separate from the reports' dataset. Check the datasource of the TargetYear shared data set on the server to see if these's a permission or other issue. The error seems to indicate there is no data source for it `Cannot create a connection to data source ' Data source for shared dataset'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)` - unless you edited the name out.